# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n=0$ iff $\rho(A)<1$ for a square matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I recently came across a theorem which says:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix. Then, $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n=0$ iff $\rho(A)<1$

I get that for a diagonizable matrix, we can find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ (where $D$ is a diagonal matrix). This would imply $A^{n}=PD^{n}P^{-1}$, and since $\rho(A)<1$,

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} D^n=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} A^{n}$

which follows directly from the fact that all elements of $D$ vanish. It is also clear that the elements can only vanish if $\rho(A)<1$ since $D$ has the eigenvalues along its diagonal thereby proving the converse.

But I am not able to figure it out for a non-diagonizable matrix. Would someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of matrix $A$, i.e, the largest absolute eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: What is $\rho(A)$? The determinant?

Comment: No $\rho$ is the spectral radius. I've edited the question now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition, we can write $A = D+N$ where $D$ is diagonalizable with the same spectrum as $A$, $N$ is nilpotent and commutes with $D$.

We have $\rho(D)<1$ so, as shown in $OP$, $D^n\to 0$. Moreover, for any fixed $k\geq 0$, we have $n^kD^n \to 0$.

Then, with $d$ such that $N^d = 0$, we have :
$$A^n=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} {n\choose k}D^{n-k}N^k$$

With $k$ fixed, ${n\choose k}$ is a degree $k$ polynomial in $n$. Therefore, we can take the limit above and get :
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} A^n = 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!